# Update redux state in reactjs with input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my application i am displaying person data.
I have a scenario where I can input new person. So far I have got this:
Reducer:

```
export default function (state = [], action) {
    console.log("Reducing");
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD':
            console.log("ADDING!");
            return action.payload;
            break;
    }
    return state;
}
```

Action:

```
export const addPerson = (person) => {
    console.log("addPerson Action Fired! ", person);
    return {
        type: 'ADD',
        payload: person
    }
};
```

I have a reducer with few person data which i am showing in my application but i am blocked at this point of adding new person. So far i can see my input in console log but can't figure out how can i add it to the state.
Help would be very much appreciated.

This is the reducer where i am showing the data from.

```
export default function () {
    return ["abc","def","ghi","jkl"]
}
```

Now i am displaying a list of these elements from the array(each are one person). When i add one it will be added with these persons and show me the updated list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do the following in your reducer:

```
export default function (state = [], action) {
    console.log("Reducing");
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'ADD':
        return [
          ...state,
          action.payload,
        ]
    }
    return state;
}
```

In this way, you add the person to your existing array. Otherwise you changes your current `state` value from an array to an object.

---

Let's consider your person object value is the following and you dispatch it:

```
{
  type: 'ADD',
  payload: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John Doe',
  }
}
```

With your previous code, you would have the current value:

```
// First step
return action.payload;

// Second step
return { id: 1, name: 'John Doe' };
```

With the corrected code:

```
// First step
return [
  ...state,
  action.payload,
]

// Second step
return [
  ...[],
  { id: 1, name: 'John Doe' },
]

// Third step
return [{ id: 1, name: 'John Doe' }];
```

Comment: Hi, I understand the procedures. But it didnot work for me. I already have a preset of person data in another reducer file which i took in the store variable and displaying. I was trying to add new data with that data. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi, can you edit your question to add more details then of from where you start (the current value) and what you expect to have (the expected value after the add) ? I'll edit my answer to answer you again accordingly !

Comment: Hi, I found my problem. The data coming from first reducer and the added person data coming from Second. I had to access the second reducer to get my data. Thank you for your help.